# A good way to separate client side templates from the main layout

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jquery-templates, mustache

What is the best way to deal with multiple client side templates?

I noticed that if I keep them in my "mother" html file, it soon gets bloated with stuff, so I thought that maybe it would be better if I just put them in separate js files and load them one by one.

Another idea of mine was to avoid putting them separately as templates, but rather write them as strings and sort of couple them with the backbone.js views which are going to use them. I know that this would bring a lot of negative from designers, web developers, and software engineers in general, but for the projects I am working on, this seems like a very speedy way to develop because I have logic and layout at the same place. Plus, by reverse engineering, I proved that a bunch of prominent web services are doing the same so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have them in separate files, but combine into one file on a server side.

And take a lot of negative from me for your idea to keep templates in strings :). It might work until they are simple, but when they get more complex it gets badly, because html structure is not so obvious, so it is harder to write css and so on.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), which includes a ['text' plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text) for templates.

You can then use the [r.js optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) to combine all of these (plus JS modules, if you go that route) into a single file.

The optimizer can be run either as part of your build process, or in-process if you're using node.js.

Answer (score 1):

As @stusmith said, require.js is a good option.

also, take a look at the boilerplate's examples

- http://backboneboilerplate.com/
- https://github.com/thomasdavis/backboneboilerplate/blob/gh-pages/js/views/backbone/page.js

cheers